# How to expire gelocations on redis

Tags: java, redis, geolocation, maps

I am using geo-support on Redis.

Adding new geolocations this way:

```
"GEOADD" "report-geo-set" "30.52439985197" "50.56539003041" "john"
```

I want to expire john key from report-geo-set after X hours.

Any suggestions doing that?

Thank you,
ray.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not possible with built-in commands. Keep in mind that geo-support based on zset and your question is look`s like "How to use TTL for individual keys in ZSET".

You may use something like that:

1. Add "john" to additional special timeout ZSET with time() + X hours score.
2. From time to time run script/worker which get all obsolete keys from timeout zset and execute ZREM for your "john" key.

Example of given suggestion. Add items:

```
MULTI
GEOADD report-geo-set 30.52439985197 50.56539003041 john
ZADD geo-timeout 1452600528 john //1452600528 is unix time stamp current + X hours 
EXEC
```

Clean up script called from time to time (with LUA):

```
local currentTime = redis.call('TIME');
local list = redis.call('ZRANGEBYSCORE', 'geo-timeout', 0, currentTime[0]);
local keysRemoved = 0;
for i, name in ipairs(list) do
    redis.call('ZREM', 'geo-timeout', name);
    redis.call('ZREM', 'report-geo-set', name);
    keysRemoved = keysRemoved + 1;
end
return keysRemoved;
```

Comment: you could also rotate the geo zsets once every hour or so and look in the last N sets.

Comment: Or, keep another Sorted Set for the same members but use a timestamp as score and periodically/on every request use it to manually expire (`ZREM`) the old members from both sets.

Comment: @misterion, add john special timeout zset with time + X hours score. could you elaborate that one? not sure I got it. thanks.

Comment: @ItamarHaber isn't the score in a geo set used for the geohash?

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer yep - that why I suggested using two sets, one for geo and on for ttl

Comment: @ItamarHaber could you create answer with your example

Comment: @misterion I never tried LUA scripts before. I am not sure about the learning curve of it right now.

Comment: @rayman - it`s just a sample. Write in Java with your redis library. It be the same - ZRANGEBYSCORE from timeout zset and next 2 ZREM. This code and @ItamarHaber sugestion is same.

Comment: @misterion, Do you think going thru all the keys this way periodically  wont be be a memory issue when having more than 1m entries ?

Comment: I don`t think it`s a problem. ZSET sufficiently RAM effective to do so. In addition, he is the fastest for your purposes.

Comment: So the only over head is on external service that will schedule that.

Comment: Yes. Or, for example, you may call such code with every N of usual operations. For every 1000th or so write/read execute such code.

Comment: @rayman the one by misterion in this answer is exactly the example I'd give.